# Delete isn't working in basic CRUD application

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, crud

I'm trying to delete a comment from the user and am having trouble figuring out why my CRUD is not working. I'm almost positive that is $(this).parent().data('id'), because my console.log ("ID", commentId) is returning ID undefined.

```
            // Delete Comment From a Meme
            $('.deletebutton').on('click', function(element) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var commentId = $(this).parent().data('id'); ////id needs to point to id of comment
                console.log("ID", commentId)
                window.glob = $(this);
                $(this).parent().remove();
                doYouLikeMeme.deletePost(commentId);
            });

        deletePost: function(commentId) {
            var DeletePost = doYouLikeMeme.url + "/" + commentId;
            $.ajax({
                url: DeletePost,
                method: "DELETE",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("WE DELETED SOMETHING", data);
                    doYouLikeMeme.getPost();

                },
                error: function(err) {
                    console.error("ugh", err);
                }
            })
        },


    };
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Do you see the console log messages, which of them? Do you get an error message? Where's the backend code that deletes the post?

Comment: @Juhana I'm almost positive it's $(this).parent().data('id'). commentID is coming back as undefined in my console.log. To give you more context, I'm appending li's to the page along with an a tag represented as an "x". 

$('.deletebutton').on('click', function(element) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var commentId = $(this).parent().data('id'); 
                console.log("ID", commentId)
                window.glob = $(this);
                $(this).parent().remove();
                doYouLikeMeme.deletePost(commentId);
            });

Comment: Yes, that code is already in the question. It's the *frontend* code. Where's the *backend* code? Which of those console log messages do you see when the function gets called?

Comment: I'm getting the ID undefined message from the console log. Coming from the ${'.deletebutton} click event

Comment: Please read the following, with the emphasis on the *minimal* - there's too much code here for a relevant question.  [mcve]

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks! I edited it to display a more specific section of my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to show the HTML also. If `$(this).parent().data('id')` returns undefined it's because the button's parent doesn't have the `data-id` attribute or it hasn't been assigned to it in jQuery. Should it be `.attr('id')`?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to include the relevant HTML because while `$(this).parent().data('id');` could easily be changed to  `$(this).closest("[data-id]").data('id)` there may be a better way and it depends on where your `id` is stored in the relative html.     Perhaps you could change the generated html so the id is on the `a`?

Answer (score 0):

If your parent element html includes an id attribute like this: `id="something"`, try this

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

If your parent element html includes a data attribute like `data-id="something"` then use .data('id') as hou have done in your code.

Comment: This should be a comment: *how is the id stored in the related html?*    Because otherwise this is just a guess.